# Mysql select random rows with multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, random, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

This is my table example:

```
id     options     playlist_id
1      ...         7
3      ...         7
4      ...         9
11     ...         9
12     ...         7
14     ...         9
```

How do I select (for example) 3 random rows for each playlist_id and group results by playlist_id?

```
select id, options
from table
where playlist_id = 7 AND playlist_id = 9
group by playlist_id 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

I expect to return 3 random rows with playlist_id = 7 and 3 random rows with playlist_id = 9

Answer (score 2):

You need the 3 random songs *per playlist*. `order by` and `limit` alone cannot do that, since they operate on the whole resultset, while you somehow need to shuffle and limit within each group.

Assuming MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` with an `order by rand()` clause; this assigns a random rank to each record within groups of records sharing the same playlist, that you can then use for filtering:

```
select id, options
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by playlis_id order by rand()) rn
    from mytable t
    where playlist_id in (7, 9)
) t
where rn <= 3
```

Comment: How much more effective is this than making query for each playlist_id alone?

Comment: @Toniq: it is (almost) always more efficient to use a single query than two: that's a single roundtrip to the server, a single query parsing and execution.

Comment: I still get this error using this query: near '(PARTITION BY playlist_id ORDER BY RAND()) rn
        FROM `wp_ap_media` t
  ' at line 5

Comment: @Toniq: which version of MySQL are you running (`select version()`)? This requires MySQL 8.0.

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)

Comment: I am not able to run this?